# mod_rewrite for redirecting a directory to a top level domain

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm brand new to writing mod_rewrites and could use some help.  I have a directory like this in my site:

```
http://domain.com/de
```

This goes to our German site.  Domain.de points to the /de folder.  So how do I write a mod_rewrite rule that will redirect like this:

```
domain.com/de/contact-us => domain.de/contact-us
domain.com/de/markets => domain.de/markets
domain.com/de/materials => domain.de/materials
```

Etc.

If you could provide the full mod_rewrite that would be great.  This noob would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will redirect any request to the de folder to your *.de domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/de/(.*)$ http://domain.de/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I think I'm missing some lines of code.  I have "RewriteEngine On" in the line above.  What else do I need other than that.  With your code, the browser thinks for a really long time and then doesn't redirect.

Comment: Put in what the full rewrite should probably look like. You might could get it to work without the HTTP_HOST.

Comment: It works without the forward slash before the /de in the third line.